# Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 12.x

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-sass

I am trying to build an Angular project but getting this error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

Error: Missing binding /XXXXXXX/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-72/binding.node

Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 12.x
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading `node` screws up `node-sass`. To fix:

> - delete `package-lock.json`
> - delete `node_modules`

```
npm rebuild node-sass
npm i
```